# Spyder crashed during last session

Tags: python, spyder

After upgrading Spyder in Anaconda from 3.3.6 to 4.0.1 using **pip install --upgrade spyder** the error message below popped up when I open the upgraded version of spyder:

*Spyder crashed during last session.*

*If Spyder does not start at all and before submitting a bug report, please try to reset setting to default by running Spyder with the command line option '--reset':*

What should I check? fix? do?

Comment: Try to reinstall Anaconda

Comment: By doing `pip install --upgrade spyder` in Anaconda you basically broke it and now you need to reinstall it. Instead you should have done `conda update spyder`. We warn about this in our [release instructions](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v4.0.1). And please don't report more bugs about this unless you reinstall Anaconda and update Spyder as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in win10 which I resolved by updating Spyder. Open Anaconda Prompt:

`conda install -c anaconda spyder`

It might take several minutes to complete.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused by not saving correctly the last time you exited.
Anaconda3 provides a self-contained tool called
`Reset Spyder Settings (Anaconda)`
to deal with this situation, which you can find in the Anaconda3 folder in the start menu. It is actually a shortcut to Spyder to perform

```
spyder --reset
```